# What does `asof` mean in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I've read the documentation for pandas. There is a useful function called `merge_asof` which appears to merge two dataframes with rows that are close together. But I don't know what `asof` means. Is it `as of`? Or is it an abbreviation for something?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "as of". Here are two sources that reference it as such:

[kdb+ and q asof](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/asof/)

[SPIP: as-of join in Spark SQL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22947)